# Add query parameters to the route in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have a paginated API that looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/articles/?page=2` and I want to use the same pagination on the front end in [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io).

I created two buttons for the `next` and `previous` pages:

```
<button
  type="button"
  click.delegate="getArticles(articles.previous)">prev</button>
<button
  type="button"
  click.delegate="getArticles(articles.next)">next</button>
```

When I click `next` there is a new `GET` request and the articles list get updated but I also want to add the parameters on the URL so the user can see he's on the second page.
So, how can I add `/?page=2` to the end of the route.

I know how to add parameters using a different component as the child but this time I'm using the same component.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurelia supports query parameters in routes out of the box. You don't need to do define `page` parameter in the route itself. All query parameters are just given to the `params` parameter of `activate` method.

```js
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router, activationStrategy } from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class Articles(Router) {
    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    activate(params) {
        this.page = parseInt(params.page || '1');

        // TODO: Load your articles from the API here
        // this.articles = <fetch call using this.page>
    }

    // This is necessary to tell Aurelia router not to reuse 
    // the same view model whenever navigating between pages
    // so that the activate method gets called each time
    determineActivationStrategy() {
        return activationStrategy.replace;
    }

    // TODO: Check if we can go to previous and next page, etc.
    nextPage() {
        this.router.navigateToRoute('articles', { page: this.page + 1 });
    }

    previousPage() {
        this.router.navigateToRoute('articles', { page: this.page - 1 });
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Anyway using `--this.page` instead of `this.page - 1` prevents a bug. Also, I didn't need `activateStrategy` in my case but was good to know, thank you.